# Android Libgdx - Why does sequence () method use run as a separate thread in the code?

Tags: android, libgdx, sequence

I am reading the Libgdx game book. In the last chapter about animation, the following code 
is used to add sequence action. However I don't understand how it works? Can some explain to me.
What is the purpose?
Thanks.

```
SequenceAction seq = sequence();

if (visible) 

seq.addAction(delay(delayOptionsButton + moveDuration));

seq.addAction(run(new Runnable() { 

public void run () { 

btnMenuPlay.setTouchable(touchEnabled); 

btnMenuOptions.setTouchable(touchEnabled); 

} 

})); 

stage.addAction(seq);
```

The book explains the following:

we always add a run() action to the sequence. The run() action takes a Runnable which is used in Java to put code that is going to be executed in a separate thread. We use this and the conditional delay() action to call setTouchable() on the Play and Options buttons which controls whether the buttons receive and respond to touches and mouse clicks. Finally, the sequence() action stored in seq is added as a new action to the stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This get Not executed in a different thread. The runnable is just an interface for the sequence to execute. So if you add a runnable the sequence knows that it can call the `.run()` on that object when it is time to execute the action (your custom runnable action). That's all. Since in java the runnable interface usually is used for executable tasks for a thread he mentioned this in the book I guess.

In general libgdx uses one single thread to execute everything. A sequence also is not parallel. Moreover close to all classes of libgdx (except the asset loader if I know that right) are not threadsave.

But to get an understanding you can always look into the code of libgdx and see what is going on and if it is for example threaded or not.

I hope this answered your question.